# Trying to execute through Hive a Select count(*) in a view with 3936 columns we are getting the error Map operator initialization failed

Tags: hive, sas, buffer

We are running a SAS job into an AWS EMR using TEZ engine and when it is executing this query through hive:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM forv03141228160142_1672177412007
```

Then we are getting this error in hive-server2.log:

```
2023-01-03T21:32:16,280 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-94([])]: SessionState (:()) - Map 1: 0(+0,-4)/1  Reducer 2: 0/1  
2023-01-03T21:32:16,280 ERROR [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-94([])]: SessionState (:()) - Status: Failed
2023-01-03T21:32:16,283 ERROR [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-94([])]: SessionState (:()) -**Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1666383011400_0273_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1666383011400_0273_1_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1666383011400_0273_1_00_000000_0:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed**
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:171)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1926)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed**
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:188)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Stack overflow during pattern compilation near index 26400
(.{10})(.{10})...(.{10})(.{10})(.{10})(.{10})(.{10})(.{10})
                                                         ^
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:286)
    ... 15 more
```

This is what SAS is receiving:

> Return codes from Hive ( SYSDBRC=-1 SYSDBMSG=HADOOP: ERROR: Prepare error: Buffer overflowSQL statement: SELECT COUNT(*) AS
> count FROM forv03141228160142_1672177412007 SQLXMSG=ERROR: Prepare error: Buffer overflowSQL statement: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count

We tried increasing the `HADOOP_HEAPSIZE`, setting the jar `commons-httpclient-3.1.jar` into the `HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH` and setting the variables: `hive.vectorized.execution` and `hive.vectorized.execution.enabled` as false, but nothing has worked

Comment: I know nothing about HIVE, but why `count(*)` in code has changed into `count()` in log? May using count() function with a specific variable name helps?

Comment: Try `COUNT(1)`.  The systems involved may be utilizing a prepared statement trying to process the `*` and getting smacked down by the 3,936 column names.  The logged exception showing regex `(.{10})(.{10})...(.{10})(.{10})(.{10})(.{10})(.{10})(.{10})` is of some concern to and understanding what is going on in `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata` will help troubleshoot.